# Как сделать отступ от левого края и отступ от верха на 4 пикселя в graphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt

Написал вот такой код:

```
graphicsScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    statebalanser = new StateBalanser(i);
    statebalanser->setPos((i * 54) % 540, (i / 10) * 42);
    graphicsScene->addItem(statebalanser);
}
```

// ui->graphicsView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft); выравнял по левому краю работает
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(graphicsScene);

```
попробовал : statebalanser->setPos((i * 54) % 540 + 4, (i / 10) * 42) + 4; не получилось закомментировал  

попробовал 'graphicsScene->setSceneRect(QRectF(4,4,544,1104));' не получилось закомментировал 

попробовал 'ui->graphicsView->setSceneRect(QRectF(4,4,544,1104));' не получилось закомментировал
```

Но все равно получил прижатость к левому краю. Как сделать отступ в 4 пикселя ?

```
    #ifndef STATEBALANSER_H
    #define STATEBALANSER_H
    #include <QGraphicsRectItem>
    #include <QPainter>
    #include <memorymap.h>

class StateBalanser : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    StateBalanser(int num);

public:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);

    void StateBalance();

    void setColorState(unsigned char value_1, unsigned char value_2);

    void setColorText(QColor text);

    void setFontText(QFont fontText);

private:
    int number;

private:
    QRectF _intersect;

    QColor _fillColorState;

    QColor _fillColorModeWork;

    QColor _fillColorText;

    QFont  _fontText;

public:
    QRectF boundingRect() const;

    QPainterPath shape() const;
};

#endif // STATEBALANSER_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "statebalanser.h"

StateBalanser::StateBalanser(int num) :
    number(num)
{
    setColorState(10,10); // 10 10

    setAcceptHoverEvents(true);

    StateBalanser::StateBalance();

    StateBalanser::setColorText(Qt::black);

    StateBalanser::setFontText(QFont("Monospace", 10));

    setToolTip(QString("Sensor %1").arg(number + 1));
}


void StateBalanser::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->fillRect(boundingRect(), _fillColorModeWork);

    painter->fillRect(_intersect, _fillColorState);

    painter->drawPath(shape());

    painter->setFont(_fontText);

    painter->setPen(_fillColorText);

    painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString("%1").arg(number + 1) );
}


void StateBalanser::StateBalance()
{
  _intersect = boundingRect().intersected(QRectF(3, 3, 44, 32));
}


void StateBalanser::setColorState(unsigned char value_1, unsigned char value_2)
{ 
   switch(value_2)
   {
   case StopBalancer :        _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#000000") ;
      break;

   case ChargeBalancer :      _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#0000ff") ;
      break;

   case DischargeBalancer :   _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#ff0000") ;
      break;

   case EsrBalancer :         _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#32CD32") ;
     break;

   case DisconnectBalancer :  _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#000000") ;
      break;

   default :                  _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
      break;
   }

   switch(value_1)
   {
   case StateGood :      _fillColorState =  QColor("#99FF99") ;
      break;

  case  StateFiftyFifty: _fillColorState =  QColor("#FFFF66") ;
     break;

  case StateFault :      _fillColorState =  QColor("#FF9999")  ;
     break;

  case StateDisconnect:  _fillColorState =  QColor("#999999") ;
     break;

  default :              _fillColorState =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
      break;
   }
}


void StateBalanser::setColorText(QColor text)
{
    _fillColorText =  QColor(text);
}


void StateBalanser::setFontText(QFont fontText)
{
    _fontText = fontText;
}


QRectF StateBalanser::boundingRect() const
{
   return QRectF(0, 0, 49, 37);
}


QPainterPath StateBalanser::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;

    path.addRect(boundingRect());

    return path;
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего, вам надо задать размер сцены QGraphicsScene::setSceneRect, без этого сцена будет автоматически "расширяться/сужаться", в зависимости от взаиморасположения своих итемов.

Comment: а что делает метод StateBalanser::setPos, можно добавить определение класса и метод? в общем случае вам надо работать с геометрией setGeometry(...)

Comment: @goldstar_labs Добавил  определение класса и метода.

Comment: @ Alexander Chernin добавил 'graphicsScene->setSceneRect(QRectF(4,4,544,1104));' сцена не изменилась не сдвинулась влево на 4 пикселя.